# Renjin incompatible with Grails application and how are asm and cglib library used in Grails

Tags: java, grails, renjin

I'm trying to use [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/) as a Jar file in our Grails application. On start up, the following exception came up:

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/core/DebuggingClassWriter
```

- Platform: Windows 7
- Grails version for the application: Grails 2.2.3
- Renjin version: 0.7.0-RC7

Top result in Google search is probably the only relevant post: [NoClassDefFoundError in Grails app using XWiki with Markdown syntax](http://www.componentix.com/blog/30/noclassdeffounderror-in-grails-app-using-xwiki-with-markdown-syntax)

It indicates there is a jar file conflict between Grails cglib-2.2/asm-3.1 and the other jar you put in the classpath. In my case, the Renjin jar file I assume.

I chose to upgrade to cglib 3.0 and asm 4.0. The conflict seems resolved. **However, the author of the post warns that there is a chance other functionality in the application may be affected.**

Of course I could re-test the whole app again (it will take some time but doable). My questions are:

- How are asm and cglib used in Grails?
- Which part of the application is likely to be affected?
- Are Renjin using cglib or asm library?

Update:

Strangely, when I create a new Grails application with Grails 2.2.3 (cglib-2.2/asm-3.1) and put the Renjin jar in the classpath, the app starts with no problem.

I did a bit search about asm and cglib. It seems that they are

> used to modify existing classes or dynamically generate classes, directly in binary form

quoted from ASM home page. So are they the library that allows us to modify Grails code and see the changes without restarting the application? Does this mean that the whole app is affected and I have to retest the whole thing?

Comment: cglib (and hence asm) is used by Spring to generate the proxy classes that make transactional services work.  Hibernate does a similar trick with proxy classes but using javassist instead of cglib.

Answer (score 0):

Renjin uses asm to compile parts of the R code on the fly. I think asm is probably another case, in addition to guava that we ought to repackage to avoid annoying version conflicts like the one you describe. Can you add an issue report on github? Also see jersey-guava for an example of how go do this and submit a pull request if you have time.